# Spring Security 3 cookie-based login with Custom Authentication Provider

Tags: spring, authentication, cookies, spring-security, single-sign-on

I'm currently using Spring Security 3.2.5. I have written a CustomAuthenticationProvider that uses an external login service which checks if user/pass is correct and then creates the Authentication with principal, pass and details (this Details section is a POJO of our User Entity). It also generates a SingleSignOn Token and creates a cookie with it, so it can "auto login" on every other app of the enviroment using this cookie.

I am wondering how this can be achieved. I can do it by calling an "autologin" method on the login page of each app, which will just call our loginservice and check if the token is valid. If it works, then manually create the Authentication object. But I am trying to integrate as much as I can with Spring Security, so it is my last option.

I have read lots of documentation (ie http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.5.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#remember-me ) on how to easy implement the "remember-me", but our token is generated in a different way (so I just cant simply use the hash-based token approach) nor accesing the database, as I must use the internal service.

So, basically, I need to create a filter that, if user is not authenticated, reads the cookie and checks if the token is valid; if it is, login; otherwise, ignore the cookie (or delete it) and let normal login (via my Custom Authentication Provider) but I don't know how to get it done.

Should I write a filter? Implement an interface?

Please, I need some guideline.